# I don't want the "t" to be capitalized in "aren't"

Tags: python, capitalization

I started two months ago with coding so I am fairly new and I am working on a codewars challenge where I have to capitalize every word in a sentence and I am kinda lost right now.

I want the "t" in "aren't" to be small but my out put always comes out to "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes **Aren'T** Real".

Additionally when I try to insert the a print method it says 'string' is not defined.
Can someone explain me what I did wrong.

If possible don't tell me the solution but give me a hint on how to solve it.

This is my code

```py
def to_jaden_case(string):
    
    string = ["how "+"can "+"mirrors "+"be "+"real "+"if "+"our "+"eyes "+"aren't 
    "+"real "]
    
    for letter in string:
             
        output = letter.title()
    
    return output
```

Comment: use triple ` to format your code.

Comment: you cant use title for this if you want the `t` after the `'` to be lower case. This is explained and covered in the docs https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.title

Comment: I wouldn't give a parameter the name `string` because it collides with the name of the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module from the Python Standard Library. Why is `string` a parameter anyway? You overwrite it in in the first line of the function. And why ist it called "string" if it is a `list`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20title#str.capitalize) instead of title().

I am not sure why are you doing it this way, you may do something like:

```
capitalized = [word.capitalize() for word in ["how ","can ","mirrors ","be ","real ","if ","our ","eyes ","aren't ","real "]]
```

This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions)

Than you may convert the list back to string, using [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I didn't know there was this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what format you're expecting from the input string, but the variable you've called string there is actually an array with a single string element.

The `+` operator simply concatenates multiple strings into 1, so:

```
string = ["how "+"can "+"mirrors "+"be "+"real "+"if "+"our "+"eyes "+"aren't 
    "+"real "]
```

is equivalent to:

```
string = ["how can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real "]
```

And your loop is only going to execute once with the full string.

To operate on individual words you could try splitting the string by spaces:

```
string = "how can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"
words = string.split(" ")
output_words = []
for word in words:
    output_words.append(word.capitalize())
output_string = " ".join(output_words)
```

`capitalize` will only capitalize the first letter, whereas `title` operates on the first letter of each word (which includes the t).  Because we split the string only on spaces "aren't" as treated as a single word so only the a is capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

your function should receive a string. You can then split that string by space to get each word, capitlise each word and join all the words back up using a space.

```py
def to_jaden_case(sentence):
    return " ".join(word.capitalize() for word in sentence.split())

original_sentence = "how can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"
new_sentence = to_jaden_case(original_sentence)
print(new_sentence)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is not too clear but what you need is probably just this:

```
' '.join(string)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question at all.